# Werewolves change gradually according to the phases of the moon. What made people think they only change on the full moon?

Tags: shapeshifters, werewolf

The werewolves in my story change gradually, being fully human on the new moon and being fully wolf when the moon is at its fullest. They only lose their minds on the night of the full moon.

If that is true, then **why does everybody think the change happens on the night of the full moon?**

The werewolves are in no hurry to correct them as they would be regarded with even more fear and suspicion.

I had thought about saying that they stay in hiding until they lose their minds, but my werewolves make up a fairly significant part of the population (about 1 in 20 people will be a werewolf), and it would mean that they couldn't interact with non-werewolves for most of the month.

A good answer will:

- Tell how werewolves could interact with society while allowing people to keep up their misconceptions
- Offer a reason that people started believing this in the first place
- Tell why nobody has ever figured out the truth

Note: Pretty much nothing is set in stone for this story, so you can change things up if you want.

Comment: Do werewolves only change at night, or only while the moon is visible (which is actually mostly during the daytime around the new moon)? I'd assume half-changed werewolves would need to hide from society to not be noticed, but that'll be a lot trickier if they have to spend virtually all of their time halfway between man and wolf. It'll be more feasible if they only change at certain times of day/night.

Comment: Please remember that we're here to answer specific questions not generate ideas. Questions that are written like discussion prompts or asking for us to brainstorm for you aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: Do the werewolves themselves think there's anything significant to the day of the full moon?

Comment: Does everyone know that werewolves exist or is it unknown/hidden? If they hide it, how?

Comment: Agree with sphennings.. I can add: this is a question that can only be answered with an *opinion* about anthropological explanations in the real world we live in. Off topic and opinion based. Please edit..

Comment: @Trioxidane everyone knows.

Comment: @sphennings I'd say the bold part is a pretty specific question.

Comment: @user37344 -- Not really! It's a wide open trawl for opinions, and it's no surprise the query got closed.

Comment: @Goodies The vast majority of the questions I've see on this Stack involve some subjective preference. I don't see how this is different.

Comment: @elemtilas It's not asking an opinion at all. Opinions may differ on what a *good* answer is, but that's true of Worldbuilding questions broadly. This may be one of the more concrete questions I've seen on this Stack.

Comment: Hi Boring Writer!  So, you've got your first rejection notice here on WB.SE!  No worries, there are a number of resources around to help you tighten up this question and to write better queries in the future. First, please review the [tour], the [help] and learn [what WB is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about)!  I'd say that you have a really good foundation for a query, but as written, you're trawling for opinions. This isn't that kind of forum. WB.SE is a Q&A where you...

Comment: (cont) ... need to ask pointed and focused questions that are as unlikely to generate hundreds of opinions as possible. We'd like to play around in your world and help you with problems and issues like this, but you'll need to work on question delivery just a little bit!

Comment: Boring Writer --- The best thing you can do is delete those last two lines and in stead, give us a couple of criteria by which you'd judge an answer to be good. This will instantly turn your fishing expedition into something much closer to a worldclass WB query! Also, since you are a writer, I'm going to straight up tell you that your formatting sucks.  Best practice is to separate your main sections: separate your introductory statement from your question; separate your question from your own deliberation / original research. Then write your answer criteria.

Comment: @user37344 -- You are 100% correct that most queries in WB involve "some subjective preference". We do draw a line here about "opinions" on how dragons can fly vs "what colour the dragon should be" or "why do people think dragons can't fly". Do you think those examples cross the line or not?  I agree that opinions can differ on what constitutes a good answer; but that's not the kind of opinion the OP is fishing for.

Comment: @elemtilas If the OP had simply said "how are changes concealed when the moon is not full?" or "what prevents people from seeing partial changes from being noticed?" or something like that would you then be on board, because I'm pretty sure that's all they're asking.

Comment: @user37344 -- I'm actually on board with the premise of the question as it is! I think I addressed this in my reply to the Boring Writer about suggested edits. The problem with the question is that she's asking for ideas, for opinions. The idea is to tighten up this kind of question so it won't generate loads of opinions like this one already has!

Comment: Re. Your edit. Adding additional criteria doesn't make your core ask less broad. It could be read as you asking 3 additional more specific questions. Fundamentally you're still asking us to do the brainstorming for you rather than answer a specific question about your world.

Answer (score 5):

**The world is full of weird and wonderful creatures.**

There are giants, ogres, unicorns, pixies, golems, humanoid swarms of locusts, superintelligent floating eyeballs, brain candy, and anything else you can imagine.

In particular there are -- in addition to the werewolves -- a separate type of  half-wolf half-man creature (wolfweres) that don't change with the moon. These guys are always in semi-wolf form.

So if I see a half-morphed werewolf on the street I just think "Oh look there's a wolfwere" and continue with my day. I am free to keep up my misconceptions about the werewolves.

Answer (score 4):

**Werewolves Do More Damage on the Full Moon**

Werewolves obviously don't want people to know their true identities, so they hide away during the nights where they are partially transformed. I'd assume they only have ears or a tail during the times where there is a crescent moon, so all they'd need is a decent hat or something, and they'd easily be able to hide that away. It gets more difficult the more the moon is revealed, but they'd probably learn to deal with it after a while, and families of werewolves would probably spend their entire lives figuring out how to keep it concealed.

The full moon is different. They completely lose their minds, and all logic goes out the window. Nothing can restrain them during this time, so this is the only time when people get to see the real transformation.

This is probably the only time where people see the death and destruction these werewolves can cause. If they've completely lost all control during a full moon, then it stands to reason that they'd also cause a lot of death and destruction in their wake.

This is what people remember every time they think of the werewolves. They think of the death, loss, and trauma that they faced when the wolves last went on a rampage.

This leads to the common myth that werewolves only exist during the full moon because that is the only time non-werewolves even see them. Every other day of the year the werewolves are trying not to be spotted. Probably because they are ashamed of what they have done, and horrified at their own natures.

Having 1 of 20 people being a wolf actually makes things easier for them to hide, because there are more people on their side trying to make sure they are not being caught. I'd imagine whole organizations existing to help werewolves avoid capture.

The werewolf organizations might even purposefully perpetuate the myth. People might not fear them as much if they think wolves are only dangerous one day out of the month.

Obviously, people who hate and fear the wolves are never going to make any attempt to understand them. In the minds of everyone else, they are probably nothing more than mindless monsters, so they would easily accept and believe any number of untrue myths about them.

People believe patently untrue things all the time, and it's not like a real werewolf would ever step in and confirm or deny these things. Then they'd probably be killed for sure.

Townsfolk who hate and despise the wolves would come up with all manner of rumors and lies to make people hate them even more, and none of the poor wolves would ever be able to do anything about it.

"Did you know a werewolf can be killed by a silver bullet? You'd better buy my whole supply of silver bullets."

"Did you know werewolves only come out during the full moon? Daylight is when they're at their weakest, so you have to kill them then."

"Did you know werewolves are 20 feet long, spit acid, and love the taste of human flesh? Even in their human forms, they can't get enough of the flavor, so they cook and eat children."

While there may be truth to some of the claims, people are blinded by their own biases. They'll believe whatever people tell them to believe. If popular opinion says wolves only come out at the full moon, that is the truth they will accept.

Answer (score 2):

## The Last minute changes are the most obvious (and stigma):

With so many werewolves in society, people assume some wolf characteristics are just normal. But most of those are relatively easy to conceal. It's not that it's totally unacceptable to be a werewolf, but there's a strong stigma. Even after shifting to quadrapedal shape, the werewolves still maintain a bipedal stance as long as possible. Too much hair gets shaved, and teeth are kept under the gums, so to speak.

The biggest, least concealable changes (snout, for example) are the last things to change, and at that point, the werewolves probably DO retreat from society to prevent harm when control is finally lost.

In fact, with so many werewolves around, there may be a practice of people staying close to home and not going out near the full moon . This may be politeness to werewolf neighbors, but also a safety practice to prevent attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Well as is always helpful, it is nice to look to the real world for inspiration, specifically, how the myth of werewolves has evolved IRL.

In the history of werewolves, early myths were often a singular change into a wolf as a form of punishment, or a change into a wolf for seven years, which could then be overturned if you did not kill any humans during that time.

It evolved over time, as it was believed that certain things like putting on a pelt of wolf skin or a belt could make you a wolf, or that a certain group of people inherited the ability to become wolves.

Many modern ideas of werewolves, such as the full moon changing wolves, lycanthropy being transmitted by a bite, or a silver bullet killing a wolf, has sprung out of the world of hollywood. When you're making a movie about werewolves, a story that involves slow changes or someone who's a wolf and nothing else changes for seven years, is a bit harder to do than someone who has a ticking clock every month - things like that and silver bullets build narrative tension.

See the video on werewolves by Overly Sarcastic Productions for the full history:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mm0KyaovhY